# csv file uploading error in Django in Mac: new-line character seen in unquoted field

Tags: python, django, csv

I created a csv file in Mac Excel and wanna upload it to my server through Django, part of my code in `views.py` is as follows:

```
        FILE_UPLOAD_DIR2 = '/mnt/opt/data/spam/'
        fd2, filepath2 = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=request.FILES['spamFile'].name, dir=FILE_UPLOAD_DIR2)
        with open(filepath2, 'wb') as dest2:
            shutil.copyfileobj(request.FILES['spamFile'], dest2)
```

But an unexpected error came out: `new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?`

I uploaded a csv file created in Windows to my server before and it worked fine, So I guess this may have something to do with the difference of the csv file created in Windows and Mac. Someone has the same problem before?

Comment: wait I don't get it, what was the problem? can you say this explicitly?

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same issue! It had to do with the way it is saved on a mac! Resave your csv and scroll down and you should see two other kinds of `.csv` files you can save it as.

Save it under the windows version and it will now be read fine!!